# Multiple databases in same AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I have an existing database in a RDS AWS PostgreSQL instance. I need to create one more database in this instance as spinning up a separate cluster will be expensive. There doesn't seem to be any option to create one more database inside this instance. I understand that I can create a separate schema for this purpose(like in MySQL) but I need to keep the resources for these separate and hence the need for a separate database.

Please let me know if it is possible.
PostgreSQL 9.6.5

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe you can. Based on AWS RDS [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/):

> Q: How many databases or schemas can I run within a DB instance?
>
> - RDS for Amazon Aurora: No limit imposed by software
> - RDS for MySQL: No limit imposed by software
> - RDS for MariaDB: No limit imposed by software
> - RDS for Oracle: 1 database per instance; no limit on number of schemas per database imposed by software
> - RDS for SQL Server: [100 databases](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon_rds_for_sql_server_increases/) per instance
> - RDS for PostgreSQL: No limit imposed by software

You can create additional database by connecting to you DB instance and do a `CREATE DATABASE`. Check this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreatePostgreSQLInstance.html)

> To create additional databases, connect to the DB instance and use the SQL command CREATE DATABASE.

And the [blog post](http://www.georgevreilly.com/blog/2016/06/28/CreatingANewPostgreSQLDatabaseAtRDS.html) on how to create new database in an existing PostgreSQL DB Instance:

```
psql --host=SOME-DBMS-HOST --dbname EXISTING_DB \
     --username=YOUR-USERNAME --password \
     --command="CREATE DATABASE new_database WITH OWNER some_owner"
```

Comment: The  key here is make sure you connect to the EXISTING_DB

Comment: instead of connecting to the db instance and running `create database`, can it be done from a cloudformation template?

Comment: Seems you cannot yet create multiple DBs with cloudformation: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13588